# typed.js jQuery trigger not working during typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) to type in some text which contains a simple jQuery modal trigger.

However I'm finding that the trigger only works once the typing has fully completed. How can I make it immediately clickable?

*(So in the example below, it only works when 'sit amet' has appeared.)*

**Typed**

```
$(".js-typed").typed({

  strings: ["Lorem ipsum dolor <a class='js-modal-trigger'>open modal</a> sit amet."],     
  showCursor: false,

});
```

**Modal**

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-modal-trigger', function(){
    $('.js-modal').addClass('active');
});
```

I already changed this from using `$('.js-modal-trigger').on('click', function() {`. But it still doesn't appear to work, until completed.

I've also wrapped the modal trigger into a function and tried using the typed.js `callback: function() {}` and `onStringTyped: function() {}`. Neither seemed to work.

How can I make the link clickable as soon as it appears in document?

Answer (score 0):

)
I'm new to typed, and just going through the GitHub stuff ...  but ....

I would think add two strings.  First completing after link (forcing the typed function to complete HTML processing) then start another string immediately.

```
$(".js-typed").typed({

strings: ["Lorem ipsum dolor <a class='js-modal-trigger'>", 
"open modal</a> sit amet."],     
showCursor: false,
```

});

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I don't think that will work because typed.js actually deletes each string once it has typed it out, apart from the last string :(

Comment: You are right ....  the code works with separate strings, but then you loose it ....  In its present state, I don't think you can achieve what is required.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for your time and help!